# Google Drive - How to Autopopulate Google Spreadsheet with Concatenate functions when users submit data via webform?

Tags: google-apps-script, concatenation, google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a Google Drive Spreadsheet in which I'm trying to have a formula autopopulate all the way down the rows, as users submit data via a webform attached to the spreadsheet. The tricky part is that I use a `CONCATENATE` function already, to perform a concatenation of  the data submitted on several columns into one single cell.

However, for the `CONCATENATE` function to work, I have to "apply" it to newly submitted rows.
Is there a way to automate the filling of this formula down the rows in the spreadsheet?

I've tried to place an `ArrayFormula` function to it, even setting the range `(A1:A)`, but I couldn't find the proper syntax for it work, if it may like this.

The function goes:

```
=CONCATENATE(CHAR(10)&X14&V14&Y14&J14&" "&K14&" "&L14&M14&N14&O14&" "&P14&" "&Q14&R14&S14&CHAR(10)&T14&"."&CHAR(10)&U14&"."&CHAR(10)&W14&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&I14&CHAR(10)&Z14&" "&AA14&CHAR(10)&AB14&AC14&AD14&AE14&AF14&AG14&AH14&"."&CHAR(10)&AI14&AJ14)
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you can do this with the functions that auto expand the result. e.g. database functions. Sounds like you are almost there, just need to find the right function.

Comment: @eddyparkinson - I've found a little script from the Script Gallery of Google Spreadsheet (AutoFormulas, by tuxincarnate[@]gmail[dot]com), which solves the trick! Just tested it with a dozen of submissions from the webform and it does what it promises, autopopulate with formulas down the columns where applied.

Comment: Whilst you have a solution already, you might like to consider for the future the following formula, which is what you were originally looking for (You don't need to use CONCATENATE since you are choosing the columns to join together with & symbol)  =arrayformula(CHAR(10)&X2:X&V2:V&Y2:Y&J2:J&" "&K2:K&" "&L2:L&M2:M&N2:N&O2:O&" "&P2:P&" "&Q2:Q&R2:R&S2:S&CHAR(10)&T2:T&"."&CHAR(10)&U2:U&"."&CHAR(10)&W2:W&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&I2:I&CHAR(10)&Z2:Z&" "&AA2:AA&CHAR(10)&AB2:AB&AC2:AC&AD2:AD&AE2:AE&AF2:AF&AG2:AG&AH2:AH&"."&CHAR(10)&AI2:AI&AJ2:AJ)  this should go in the second row

Comment: **@DavidTew**: Thanks David for your suggestion! It is far better than the solution I've found earlier. I tested the 'ArrayFormula' and it's just what I wanted, I just didn't know I could use it alone. **Thanks again for your help!**

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Transformed into a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I've found a little script from the Script Gallery of Google Spreadsheet (AutoFormulas, by tuxincarnate[@]gmail[dot]com), which solves the trick! Just tested it with a dozen of submissions from the webform and it does what it promises, autopopulate with formulas down the columns where applied.

```
// Updates all rows except the last to have the same formulas as row 3 (allowing for a header and different row 2 formula)
// To activate this functionality, the last row in the column should have the value '(auto)'
function UpdateFormulas() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetCount = ss.getNumSheets();

  for (var sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < sheetCount; ++sheetIndex) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[sheetIndex];

    var rowCount = sheet.getMaxRows();
    var columnCount = sheet.getMaxColumns();

    if (rowCount < 5) continue;

    for (var columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; ++columnIndex) {
      if (sheet.getRange(rowCount, columnIndex).getValue() == '(auto)') {
        var row3Range = sheet.getRange(3, columnIndex);
        for (var rowIndex = 4; rowIndex < rowCount; ++rowIndex) {
          if (sheet.getRange(rowIndex, columnIndex).isBlank()) {
            row3Range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(rowIndex, columnIndex));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

@David Tew wrote:

> Whilst you have a solution already, you might like to consider for the future the following formula, which is what you were originally looking for (You don't need to use `CONCATENATE` since you are choosing the columns to join together with & symbol)

```
=arrayformula(CHAR(10)&X2:X&V2:V&Y2:Y&J2:J&" "&K2:K&" "&L2:L&M2:M&N2:N&O2:O&" "&P2:P&" "&Q2:Q&R2:R&S2:S&CHAR(10)&T2:T&"."&CHAR(10)&U2:U&"."&CHAR(10)&W2:W&CHAR(10)&CHAR‌​(10)&CHAR(10)&I2:I&CHAR(10)&Z2:Z&" "&AA2:AA&CHAR(10)&AB2:AB&AC2:AC&AD2:AD&AE2:AE&AF2:AF&AG2:AG&AH2:AH&"."&CHAR(10)&‌​AI2:AI&AJ2:AJ)
```

> this should go in the second row

The OP wrote:

> @DavidTew showed me a clear and easy way to have it solved. The ArrayFormula should go alone, telling it to put together the ranges for every column into every single row. Works like charm. Proper syntax is: `=arrayformula(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C)`, in order to have contents from cells `A2`, `B2` and `C2` "concatenated" into the cell where the `ArrayFormula` is applied. The most important issue is that by using this function, it autpopulates all the way down the rows as users submit data via a webform attached to the spreadsheet.